# Ajax tab content loading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So, I have a 2 tabs as following:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <a href="#tab1" class="active-tab tab" id="tab1-id">Tab 1</a>
  <a href="#tab2" class="tab" id="tab2-id">Tab 2</a>      
</div>
<div class="active-panel" id="tab1">
  Tab 1 content
</div>
<div class="panel" id="tab2">
  <!--Tab 2 content located in tab2.php-->
</div>
```

Then here is my script:

```
jQuery("#tab2-id").click(function(){
    jQuery("#tab2").load("tab2.php");
});
```

The file location is as following:`parts/tab1.php` and `parts/tab2.php`

So, my logic is that when the `Tab 2` is clicked, then I want to load `tab2.php` in the `div id="tab2"`.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

After the correct location syntax was pointed out, I am getting 404 error that the browser could not find `http://example.com/parts/tab2.php`. But `tab2.php` is a simple few div file and maybe I am missing something. I will do some digging around and find out why I am getting this error and put what I find in here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct location

```
jQuery("#tab2-id").click(function(){
    jQuery("#tab2").load("/parts/tab2.php");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added `/` as suggested, but I am getting an error that the page could not be found as if the `/parts/tab2.php` is a page. (http://example.com/parts/tab2.php)

Comment: @steveKim, you said the file is located in `parts/tab2.php`. Is `parts` the root path?

Comment: @steveKim, try `jQuery("#tab2").load("/tab2.php");`

Comment: @steveKim, what was the reason? Let me know so I can update my answer

Comment: Well, I was using wordpress and realized that `parts` was the not the root path. I relocated the files to root path and I got it working that way. Thank you for your help.